# Magento 2.3.3 script errors in console

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.3.3 script errors in console. I have correct folder permissions set. Tried both Luma and Ultimo theme. Cleared static directory and regenerated content. Nothing has solved this issue? Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please update and specify in your question what's the meaning of 'correct folder permissions'. For instance, what about user / group ownership of both folders & files?

Comment: I have set permissions according to the magento 2.3 guidelines. I also tried with 777 across entire magento root folder temporarily on a development box. Console errors doesn't seem to disappear. Also please note that the page is loading and I am able to see contents including categories and products and I have no issues in with their functionality.

Comment: You have to click on the script at the right e.g. on `console-output-handler.min.js:2:148` and inspect the error to find the cause.

Comment: Have you checked, .htaccess is exists in pub/static folder or not ? If there no htaccess upload a .htaccess from default magento.

Comment: I am using nginx. And .htaccess is present in the directory.

Comment: Ok so you mean your website is working fine but getting lots of errors in consol correct?

Comment: If You Use Nginx then no need to .htaccess and also you have enabled the sign static files from the backend.
Disable this and then try again.

Comment: @Zoya Please let me know is it fresh Magento 2.3.3? can you add any theme or modules?

Comment: @Zoya did you run setup:upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure `.htaccess` file is present with in `var`, `pub/static`, `pub` and `generated` folder, if not present then first you need to add `.htaccess` file as per Magento's standards.

Then run the below command to Magento root directory and set Magento ownership and user permissions for files and folders

**Syntax:** `sudo chown -R [USER NAME]:[USER NAME] /var/www`

**Command:** `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data magento2`

> *Note: Where `www-data` you need to set your user and group, set your directory name at magento 2*

Then run all the below commands:

```
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/ generated/code/ var/cache/ generated/metadata/ var/page_cache/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:upgrade
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reset
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento indexer:reindex
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
php -dmemory_limit=8G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/ generated/
```

I hope above steps would solve your problem.

Comment: i have already done this. This hasn't helped

Answer (score 0):

@zoya
Please can you goto your server files directory and see if error_log is generated there or in public_html folder. If this is after some customization then the module you added might be buggy and removing it will let you work normally.

After an upgrade magento sometimes gives jason js error

Specifically, this line inside page's html is causing the error:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": }}</script>
```

Solution is to create plugin for appendLayoutConfiguration() function:

```
public function aroundAppendLayoutConfiguration(
    \Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result $result,
    \Closure $closure
) {
    $layoutConfiguration = $this->wrapContent(json_encode($this->utf8ize($this->structure->generate($this->component))));
    $this->template->append($layoutConfiguration);
}
```

Or for clear data

```
public function utf8ize($data) {
    if (is_array($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data[$key] = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else if(is_object($data))
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            $data->$key = $this->utf8ize($value);

    else
        return utf8_encode($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Still you need to see error log or run magento in developers mode

Answer (score -3):

Remove `pub/static` folder and run `static-content:deploy`, after deploy give **777** permission to `pub/static` and `generated` folder.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have already tried that. Issue still exists.